# General/Specific Assitance in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, virtual

So I'm very new to C++ but have a dabble in C. But I have no idea how to call upon functions and variables within a private/public class. I've tried researching on pointers, but I can't seem to understand how to call upon these variables even with pointers. The code I was given is as seen below:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Thing
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
    virtual int doStuff()
    {
        return x+y;
    }
    virtual int doStuff2()
    {
        return x*y;
    }
public:
    Thing(){
        x = 2;
        y = 10;
    }
};

int extractThing(void* thing)
{
//insert code here 
//return the value to be printed

}

int main()
{
    Thing thing;
    printf("%d\n", extractThing(&thing));
    return 0;
}
```

The main goal is to display thing.x, thing.y, thing.dostuff1(), and thing.dostuff2()
I understand that because the "dostuff" functions are private, only things within that class can access that data. If you could help me understand/lead me in the right direction for coding a solution for these 4 tasks, that would be great. Thank you

Comment: In your example I suspect you want your member variables (`x`, `y`) to be `private` but your member functions (`doStuff`, `doStuff2`) to be public.

Comment: There is nothing useful that `extractThing` can do to help you. It is a free function, so it is not a member of the `Thing` class, and therefore cannot access any `private` members. Therefore, it cannot call the `doStuff` functions, nor directly access the `x` or `y` members.

Comment: General/Specific those two are pretty much mutually exclusive.

Comment: Also, don't pass a `void*` to `extractThing` when you intend to pass an instance. Use `int extractThing(Thing &thing)` instead.

Comment: @Borgleader which is presumably why OP chose to explicitly state that either assistance is appreciated by mentioning them in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You want `dostuff1` and `dostuff2` to be `public` so you can call them.  You also want a `public` `display` member function to display `x` and `y`, something like:

```
class Thing
{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    void display()
    {
            printf("%d, %d\n", x, y);
    }
    int doStuff()
    {
        return x+y;
    }
    int doStuff2()
    {
        return x*y;
    }
    Thing(){
        x = 2;
        y = 10;
    }
};
```

also, there's no reason to have `virtual` functions.

Then you can:

```
int main()
{
    Thing thing;
    thing.dostuff();
    thing.dostuff2();
    thing.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* declare `extractThing` a friend of `Thing` which means that it may access `Thing`'s privates. That's not probably the best design choice in this case though.

Since `extractThing` accepts a `Thing` instance as a parameter anyway and apparently needs to access it's private state, there's little reason not to make a member function instead.

Another option would be to give `Thing` public methods that can be used "extract" what you need from it and use those in `extractThing`.

As a sidenote, you should probably avoid throwing away type safety by passing a `void` pointer to `extractThing`.